# Jquery - Add a class to a list of <li> one at a time, every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

So as my title suggest. For a website I'm building, I need to add a class of 'active' to a list of `<li>` on the page.

Sometimes there will be six `<li>`, sometimes 17. It needs to be dynamic.

Then I need to add the class to each `<li>` in order, one at a time, every 5 seconds.

---

I was thinking, I could maybe have a counter to count all the `<li>`, and have a recurring function that adds the class to the first one and adds to another counter. When that counter hits the original counter for all the `<li>` it would stop. But then it would have to occur every 5 seconds.

Any help or advice would be appreciated

-JOPA

Comment: `counter%length` ? Show us your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to select the element at index n within the matched set. Use `setInterval` to invoke the handler after `specified-interval`

```js
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  var c = counter % $('li').length;
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('li').eq(c).addClass('active');
  ++counter
}, 5000);
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/m8y8a0s9/1/)